# How to keep the data persistent after doing a refresh to the page in vue / vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, reload, persistent-storage

*Vuejs version: 3.8.2*

**Problem**

I'm having the problem that when I'm in the video section, the data is not maintained after a refresh to the page. In other words, the value of the props does not exist

For the part of the video I created a video Component that receives several props

```
<Video :Id="id" :Title="title" :Eps="eps" :Synopsis="synopsis" :ContentType="types.content"/>
```

My intention is to be able to maintain the data even if I refresh the page.

**LatestAnimeVideo.vue**

**Template**

```
<template>
  <!-- all content -->
  <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col bg-white overflow-hidden">
    <!-- top bar -->
    <div class="border-b flex px-6 py-2 items-center flex-none">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <h3 class="text-grey-darkest mb-1 font-extrabold"> Video Section</h3>
            <div class="text-grey-dark text-sm truncate">
               Enjoy the world of anime 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-1 justify-center hidden sm:flex">
          <v-suggest :data="latest" type="text" placeholder="Search Anime ..." show-field="title" v-model="latestModel" class="border border-grey px-8 py-2 w-1/2 max-w-md outline-none rounded-l"></v-suggest>
          <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Search Anime ..." class="border border-grey px-3 py-2 w-1/2 max-w-md outline-none rounded-l"/> -->

            <button class="flex justify-center items-center bg-grey-lighter px-6 border border-grey border-l-0 rounded-r focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100">

            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="w-5 opacity-50"><g>
              <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
              </g>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- href links to platforms and social media -->
        <div class="flex justify-start items-center text-gray-500">
          <a href="https://github.com/ChrisMichaelPerezSantiago/ryuanime" class="block flex items-center hover:text-gray-700 mr-5">
            <svg class="fill-current w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
              <title>GitHub</title>
              <path d="M10 0a10 10 0 0 0-3.16 19.49c.5.1.68-.22.68-.48l-.01-1.7c-2.78.6-3.37-1.34-3.37-1.34-.46-1.16-1.11-1.47-1.11-1.47-.9-.62.07-.6.07-.6 1 .07 1.53 1.03 1.53 1.03.9 1.52 2.34 1.08 2.91.83.1-.65.35-1.09.63-1.34-2.22-.25-4.55-1.11-4.55-4.94 0-1.1.39-1.99 1.03-2.69a3.6 3.6 0 0 1 .1-2.64s.84-.27 2.75 1.02a9.58 9.58 0 0 1 5 0c1.91-1.3 2.75-1.02 2.75-1.02.55 1.37.2 2.4.1 2.64.64.7 1.03 1.6 1.03 2.69 0 3.84-2.34 4.68-4.57 4.93.36.31.68.92.68 1.85l-.01 2.75c0 .26.18.58.69.48A10 10 0 0 0 10 0">
              </path>
            </svg> 
          </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- content inside -->
    <div class="px-6 py-4 flex-1 overflow-y-scroll scrollbar" id="style-1">
      <div v-if="isLoading">
        <div class="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-wrap" v-else>
        <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/2 xl:w-1/2 mb-4">
          <Video :Id="id" :Title="title" :Eps="eps" :Synopsis="synopsis" :ContentType="types.content"/>
        </div>

         <!--  aside -->
        <aside class="w-full md:max-w-xs xl:max-w-full xl:w-1/4 md:pl-5 mt-5 md:mt-4">
          <!-- up next -->
          <div class="w-full">
            <div class="flex w-full items-center justify-between mb-3">
              <span><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i> Select Episode
                <!-- select episode -->
                <select class="list-reset border border-purple-200 rounded w-20 font-sans" v-model="eps">
                  <option v-for="(episode , index) in Array.from({length: types.totalEps}, (v , k) => k + 1)"
                    :value="episode"
                    :key="index"
                    >
                    {{ episode }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </span>

            </div>

            <h1>{{eps}}</h1>
            <div class="max-w-sm rounded shadow-2xl border-indigo-900 overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
              <img class="w-full" :src="poster" :alt="title">
            </div>

          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- footer -->
    <Footer/>

  </div>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
  import Footer from "./Footer"
  import Video from '../components/Video'
  import {mapState , mapGetters} from 'vuex'
  import store from '../store/store'

  export default {
    name: "home",
    components:{
      Video
    },
    data(){
      return{
        latestModel: '',
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        title: this.$route.params.title,
        synopsis: this.$route.params.synopsis,
        poster: this.$route.params.poster,
        types:{
          totalEps: this.$route.params.type.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') || 25, //,
          content: this.$route.params.type.split('/')[0]
        } ,
        eps: 1,
      }
    },
    computed:{
      ...mapState(['latest' , 'isLoading']),
    },
    created(){
      store.dispatch('GET_LATEST_DATA')
    },
  };
</script>
```

**Error**

This same error is shown to me for the other values defined in data.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"

found in

---> <Home>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"749ccce8-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/LatestAnimeVideo.vue?vue&type=template&id=12923488&scoped=true& (app.js:3674), <anonymous>:133:48)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4548)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4304)
    at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906)
```

**store**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import {state} from './state';
import {actions} from './actions';
import {mutations} from './mutations';
import {getters} from './getters'; 

import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
});
```

Comment: Look into [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) (frontend), cookies (frontend), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (frontend), sessions (backend), or databases (backend), depending on your needs.

Comment: @Dan I'm using createPersistedState but it does not do anything, it throws me the same errors.

I included the part of the store above.

Comment: The error indicates `types` is `undefined` (based on your usage of `types.content` in the template). The stacktrace shows the error coming from the `Home` component, but the template you've shown in the question indicates `LatestAnimeVideo.vue`. What is the template for `Home`?